# Maximum Theorem and minimized value function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we were minimizing $f(x,\theta)$ over $x\in D(\theta)$ , where $f$ and $D$ meet all the conditions of the Maximum theorem. What can one say about the minimized value function?

$$f^*(x,\theta)= \min \{f(x,\theta)│x\in D\}$$

and the correspondence of minimizers

$$D^*(\theta)= \text{argmin} \{f(x,\theta)│x\in D(\theta)\}$$

---

Here is my question (I have only learned applied calculus before) .

What does this question ask me to do? I has no idea at all.
Is it asking me to confirm that the minimized value function also meets all the conditions of Maximum theorem ? Is it because Maximum is equal to Minimum at the same time?
Do I have the right thought about this question?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

It's about [the maximum theorem](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Maximum_theorem), which is basically a theorem about continuity of $f^*$, the optimal value function, and the corresponding set-valued function $D^*$.

I guess it is a question about the case when you minimize $f$, rather than maximize it. Note that [the maximum theorem](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Maximum_theorem) basically says about the case of maximization, and your problem considers "min" and "argmin" instead of "max" and "argmax."